# Sql Transaction NetWork Performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to find which is method is more effective if i will communicate through network in sqlserver;
Till now i have two options,
One is to run each query separately, example:

```
Insert into Customers (name) values (Name1);
Insert into Customers (name) values (Name2);
Insert into Customers (name) values (Name3);
```

And a second one is to create a transaction;

```
Begin Transaction;
Insert into Customers (name) values (Name1);
Insert into Customers (name) values (Name2);
Insert into Customers (name) values (Name3);
Commit;
```

Also what method is more suitable if  many clients will send data at the same time?

Comment: is that in ONE batch or not? 2nd is more expensive, but if you run a batch per line THAT is what makes it slow. Also define "network". Internet? 100G?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shorter the lock the better. Long transactions can lead to both performance degradation (long resource wait) and deadlock. If you do not plan to process exactly the passage of "three" requests - the first option is better.

Rollback if error in one of them

```
TRY
BEGIN
    Begin Transaction;
    Insert into Customers (name) values (Name1);
    Insert into Customers (name) values (Name2);
    Insert into Customers (name) values (Name3);
    Commit;
END
CATCH
BEGIN
    THROW;
    ROLLBACK;
END
```

Comment: Yes but what if third query will fail? I dont want to have missing data inside my database, i need to be executed all of them.

Comment: What will you do if one of the requests returned with an error?

Comment: Propably i will delete others? But what is it fastest? delete the others or using transaction?

Answer (score 0):

A SQL statement always runs in a transaction. If you don't start one explicitly, every SQL statement will run in a transaction of itself.

The only choice is whether you bundle multiple statements in one transaction. Transactions that span multiple statements leave locks that hurt concurrency. So "always" creating a transactions is not a good idea. You should balance the cost against the benefit.

You can get more information from :https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43254/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-always-create-a-transaction